# Angular datepicker supporting multiple date formats

Tags: angular, date, datepicker

I have a requirement where the user can key in in a date. When manually entering the date, it needs to be either 'DD-MM-YYYY','DD/MM/YYYY' or 'DD MMM YYYY' format. When leaving the input field the value needs to be shown in 'DD MMM YYYY' format. I created a reactive form that does this and also validates if a valid date was entered:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dateForm = new FormGroup({
      userDate: new FormControl('',{ validators: [dateValidator], updateOn: "blur"})
    });
    
    this.dateForm.controls['userDate'].valueChanges.subscribe( value => {
      var date = moment(this.dateForm.controls['userDate'].value, ['DD-MM-YYYY','DD/MM/YYYY','DD MMM YYYY'] , true);
      if (date.isValid() ) {
        const currentValue= this.dateForm.controls['userDate'].value;
        const newValue = date.format('DD MMM YYYY');
        if (newValue != currentValue ) {
        this.dateForm.controls['userDate'].setValue(date.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
        console.log('update');
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

This seems to work fine BUT now I need to also be able to have the user select a date from the datepicker and then show the selected date in the same input field. If I use a standard datepicker I will loose the above functionality.

So my initial idea is now to add a datepicker and somehow have the associated input field 'invisble' and then update the value in the control above with the value selected in the datepicker. Does this sound feasible at all ? Quite new to angular so maybe theres better options ?